# Script to access and assign values from a nested object

Tags: pdf, combobox, javascript-objects, field

I have a script (provided below) created to extract and assign values from a nested object to text fields residing on a PDF form. Unfortunately, the script fails resulting in a number of undefines due to what appears to be a Null f value. To clarify, the event.value is a value selected by the user that gets assigned to a combo box on the form. Hence, for whatever reason, the combo box selection is not getting assigned to variable 'f' in which event the script fails and results in undefines for the field values on the form. I am contemplating that the solution requires a minor script adjustment for accessing the objects values. Thank you ahead of time.

```
var oField = getField("dataSource");
oVendors = JSON.parse(oField.value);
  for(j=0;j<14;j++){
    f=getField("inf."+j);
    f.value = oVendors[event.value][j];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Upon further reading and learning about how to create and use a JS 
object, the initial script posted was entirely wrong. The script 
required to extract and assign values from a JS object to text fields 
residing on a PDF form is as follows:

dsFld =getField("dataSrc");// dataSrc is a hidden text field that 
resides on the PDF form
oVendors = JSON.parse(dsFld.value);//parse oVendors, a JS object stored 
as a JSON string in the hidden dataSrc field 
btnDel=getField("btn.del");
var oFld;//declare var oFld for later use
var oPassData = oVendors[event.value];//assign a field value to var 
oPassData
if(oPassData){
//walk members to fill form fields
for(var nNm in oPassData){ // skip fields that don't exist on form
  oFld = this.getField("inf." + nNm);
  if(oFld)
  oFld.value = oPassData[nNm]// assign property values stored in 
  oVendors data object to associated PDF form fields
}

Sorry for my initial post and any inconvenience to the forum.
```